# Can Banks legally use Encrypted Ledgers like in Private coins?

Tags: united-states, criminal-law, privacy, european-union, banking

Seeing so much news about blockchains and banks I have a question that I may need your help.

Taking in consideration the Bank Secrecy Act, can a Bank use a completely Encrypted Ledger? KYC is still required, deposits and withdraws will still be reported if one deposits/withdraws more than $10k. But the bank has no idea about users' balances or their transactions. So, the bank uses an encrypted ledger that doesn't have a key to be decrypted. Namely, the ledger is encrypted in a way in which transactions are encrypted and unlinkable. Only the users can decrypt their balances and spend their funds with a... hardware token. Using this hardware tokens users can give a proof to the bank that the balance was right. Something like how is done in blockchains solutions focused on privacy.

Can public/private banks in the future use encrypted Ledgers? 
If yes why banks didn't do it until now. 
If no, why banks can't use encrypted Ledgers?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site.  We ask people to use tags indicating what jurisdiction they are asking about.  From your reference to the Bank Secrecy Act, I suppose you are asking about the United States?  You can edit your question to add the [tag:united-states] tag.

Comment: This won't work because it would make every bank a money launderers dream - while the $10K limit might be one that everyone talks about, banks are interested in any amount deposited or moved around (one of the things they are watching out for is "structuring", where you are deliberately keeping your transactions under the $10K limit).  Given the auditing and legal requirements around traceability, an encrypted ledger that the bank has no access to just wouldnt get implemented.

Comment: @Moo thanks for the reply. I understand your concern. But where in the law states that  a bank is not allowed to have an encrypted ledger? This feature enables the bank to not be hacked. Banks in XVI century were used to have encrypted ledgers.

Comment: @ElliotScot as the other comment says, add a jurisdiction you are interested in and you will get answers for that jurisdiction - right now, asking for specific laws involved without specifying a jurisdiction you are interested in means your question is far too broad and will be closed as such.

Comment: @Moo any jurisdiction US or European Union.

Comment: @ElliotScot and given the fact that end users are far more likely to be hacked than the banks themselves, with users literally giving money away to fraudsters quite willingly, I think you are pursuing the wrong solution here.

Comment: @Moo many people (like me) want to have full control of their funds. If hackers hack me, that is it. I moved on because they hacked me and it was my fault. Maybe this bank introduce sms confirmations, etc. My question, what does the law states about an encrypted ledger.

Comment: [UK legislation on money laundering and traceability](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2019/253/contents/made) and [UK guidance on information that must accompany electronic transfer of funds](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/how-to-comply-with-eu-payments-regulation) and [Interpretive guidance on funds transfer regulations](https://www.ukfinance.org.uk/system/files/UK-Finance-How-To-Guide-for-the-Funds-Transfer-Regulation-Aug-2018-002.pdf) are all probably good reading for you.

Comment: Your suggestions for how it would work are flawed as well - if the bank knows nothing about transactions or balances, how are they going to report transactions they are required to report?  They would have to depend on the user reporting the transaction to the bank, and that means the reporting system breaks down because the user is inherently untrusted in this scenario (terrorist group bankrollers, money launderers, tax evaders etc).  The bank needs full and unfettered access to balances, account details and transaction details to fulfil its legal obligations (as linked in previous comment).

Comment: Any bank that trusts the user to report on key things is a bank that wont be in business for long.

Comment: @Moo as far as I understand, the bank will report the deposit and withdraws of an individual >= 10k because deposits and withdraws still require kyc but what users do, we don't know.

Comment: @ElliotScot but you said that banks have no idea about their customers balances or transactions, so how would they know when the transaction needed to be reported?

Comment: If the bank has a completely encrypted ledger, how can they tell you how much money you have? They need to know, so they can give you your money back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## No

So far as I'm aware there is no law explicitly against an "encrypted ledger" but retail banks have legal obligations that can only be met by awareness of activity in user accounts. They entail being able to see user accounts at transaction level.

E.g. rules relating to

- money laundering
- terrorism financing
- serious crime financing
- other activity considered suspicious in the jurisdiction
- reporting on certain customers (persons or entities) under the Common Reporting Standard
- risk, exposure
- how much money the user had that is 'guaranteed' to be paid in the event of a crash

In at least the past decade the legal trends are towards *greater* transparency and traceability, *less* anonymity and financial privacy, and directly opening financial records to law enforcement authorities. And now we have Open Banking in the UK, EU and I think developing in the USA where the biggest banks are (going to be) obliged to facilitate licensed startups direct access to user accounts.

That's all aside from the bank being able to meet its obligations per the contract with the user and check the user is meeting his contractual obligations too. E.g.

- is the user attempting to withdraw money over a threshold that he may not exceed?
- did the user exceed their authorised overdraft (therefore can be charged higher interest and/or penalty)
- calculating interest due either way (to the user or bank's benefit)
- whether the account qualifies for positive or negative treatment due to frequency of withdrawals (e.g. supersaver account attracting higher interest may allow only five withdrawals a year)
- investigating user complaints (e.g. fraudulent transactions or mistakes)
- fixing mistakes
- processing credits and debits
- processing penalties
- freezing or blocking certain amounts

(Indeed how could such a business operate as a retail bank?)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was thinking just to allow financial transactions between parties using an encrypted ledger.

Comment: @ElliotScot A business providing transfer of funds services in the EU must comply with this https://www.gov.uk/guidance/how-to-comply-with-eu-payments-regulation

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 1):

### Banks need to know the balance in each of their accounts

The business of banking is taking the money of their depositing customers and lending it to their borrowing customers. They are subject to strict prudential laws about how much of the former they can lend to the latter; they need to know the balances to do this. Further, they make money by charging their borrowers interest and paying interest to their depositors and keeping the difference; they need to know the balances to calculate the interest. Further, they are generally public companies and need to be audited by law; the auditors need to be able to see the transactions to do this.

Comment: I was talking about bank that simply allows individuals to transfer funds between their accounts anonymously. Maybe the banks will change 5% of deposits/withdraws.

Comment: "The business of banking is taking the money of their depositing customers and lending it to their borrowing customers" - not in modern times. See _Money creation in the modern economy_ by Michael McLeay, Amar Radia and Ryland Thomas of the Bank of England’s Monetary Analysis Directorate. https://www.bankofengland.co.uk/-/media/boe/files/quarterly-bulletin/2014/money-creation-in-the-modern-economy

Comment: Let's say PayPal instead of a traditional bank that lends money. I talking about a financial enterprise that has its own fully ledger encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

"Encrypted Ledgers", as used by blockchain cryptocurrencies, are **no good** for banks.

In blockchain cryptocurrencies encryption/cryptography is mainly used to:

- Facilitate the integrity of *distributed / decentralised* ledger so that anyone could see mathematical proof that the ledger has not been tampered with.

  One could assume that has a value for banks too: look, our ledger is encrypted / modern / cool / bla-bla-bla. But not so.  Doing this for ledgers controlled by *one party* (e.g. bank) does not prove the integrity because the party can always make changes retrospectively and re-calculate all hashes; unlike decentralised ledgers, it can just do it without having to agree on / coordinate those changes with anyone. You would have to keep historic clones of the bank's ledger yourself to verify that the bank does not tamper with it. Who is going to do this? And even if someone does, how to prove that they have not tampered with their clone to frame the bank? Lack of decentralization means lack of point.
- Cover the asses of the money owners / senders / recipients. This just goes against of what banks legally must do: keep the asses bare.

Comment: Whether the blockchain is useful or not here depends on whether the blockchain is published - publish it widely enough and often enough and centralised ledgers become a non-issue.   Take this example of a blockchain-like approach dating back to the 1990s, which involves a published hash in a popular national newspaper to validate against (and thus changing history becomes somewhat difficult even for the single owner of the ledger) - https://www.vice.com/en_us/article/j5nzx4/what-was-the-first-blockchain

Comment: @Moo Funnily enough, these days that approach is difficult: published copies are digital only, and many independent members of the public must keep them available for verification (otherwise it's not that difficult to convince few copy holders to alter them).

Comment: Perhaps they could be stored in a distributed ledger of ledgers....

Comment: I am talking about a fully encrypted blockchain like monero, etc.

Comment: @ElliotScot That doesn't change the answer. Decentralisation is still required for such a "fully encrypted" blockchain to work and be trusted, and no bank would relinquish central control (otherwise who would need that bank?). Also, with "full encryption" like Monero asses are even better covered.

Comment: Look. Bitcoin and other cryptocurrencies have two distinct properties. 1. Decentralization. 2. Anonymity. I was talking only about anonymity feature. Would it be legal for a bank to have a fully encrypted ledger making every account anonymous.

Comment: @ElliotScot Then the second point of my answer, and also DaleM's answer work. When the authorities ask a bank who those $10M came from and where he got them from, the bank must tell full names and addresses.

Comment: @Greendrake from my understanding the Gov can only ask about a transaction and this bank will provide the encrypted transaction that no one in the world can decrypt it...

Comment: @ElliotScot your understanding is not correct. Banks around the world work under [Know your customer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Know_your_customer) regulations that require them to disclose the details of account holders and qualifying transactions to government regulators. Simply providing the encrypted version of the qualifying transactions would be material non-compliance.

Comment: @user28517 It's irrelevant if the organization that has all your fiat money doesn't recognize the ledger you think is the legitimate one.